# the code below shows error, must be some syntax error

Tags: lightning-web-components

```
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import getMyEstimate from '@salesforce/apex/estimatevsPipeline.getMyEstimate';
import getTeamEstimate from '@salesforce/apex/estimatevsPipeline.getTeamEstimate';
export default class App extends LightningElement {    
   @track TeamEstimate;
   @api oppId = '';

   // MyEstimate
   @wire(getMyEstimate)
   getMyEstInfo({ error, data }) {
      if (error) {
         // debugger;
     } else if (data) {
         this.MyEstimate = data[0].sumAmount;
     }
   // TeamEstimate
   @wire(getTeamEstimate)
   getEstInfo({ error, data }) {
      if (error) {
         // debugger;
     } else if (data) {
         this.TeamEstimate = data[0].sumAmount;
     }
   };
}
```

receiving error just after "// TeamEstimate". any suggestions?

Comment: if i remove code between the both comments in the code, it works fine

Comment: Might be the semicolon on the second-last line.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please only use relevant tags; this question has nothing to do with `salesforcedx` or `lightning-aura-components`.

Comment: We also ask that you make a good-faith effort to solve your issue. You should be able to spot the syntax error if you simply compare your two wire methods.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a closing curly bracket:

```
@wire(getMyEstimate)
getMyEstInfo({ error, data }) {
    if (error) {
        // debugger;
    } else if (data) {
        this.MyEstimate = data[0].sumAmount;
    }
} // This bracket was missing
```

Using an IDE would have pointed out this error immediately:

[image: Syntax Checking]

Notice how the method starts with a purple `{` but "ends" with a blue `}`. This lets you know immediately where your mistake was. Consider using an IDE that provides colored brackets.